# Saving django OneToOneField current user with modelform

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have spent a good few hours looking over the documentation and on here as well and i still can't find an answer to my issue. please if you know of one direct me to it. otherwise please look at the following issue. I receive a KeyError when trying to register a user as a host for an open source homestay project im working on: https://github.com/castaway2000/OpenStay this is yet to be pushed to the master branch. i have tried setattr() and instance as well. something just isn't clicking with me on this one.

models.py

```
class HostRegistration(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

forms.py

```
class HostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #no need for charfields here because we refrence the model with the fields
    class Meta:
        model = HostRegistration
        fields = ['address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'country']
```

views.py - the problem starts here XD

```
# become a host
def host_register(request):
user = request.user
if user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        host_form = HostForm(data=request.POST)
        if host_form.is_valid():
            host_form.fields['user'].instance = user.id  # this is where its failing.
            host = host_form.save(commit=False)
            print host
            host.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/edit_userpage/')
        else:
            print host_form.errors
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
guide_form = HostForm()
context = {'guide_form': guide_form}
return render(request, 'users/host.html', context)
```

please let me know how to access the model object 'user' in my views and save the currently logged in user as a reference to it with the modelform. it would be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer.

i changed my model.py to

```
class HostRegistration(models.Model):
    # user is the changed variable
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

and i updated my views.py to:

```
def host_register(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            host_form = HostForm(data=request.POST)
            if host_form.is_valid():
                instance = host_form.save(commit=False)  # this is the trick.
                instance.user = request.user  # and this to get the currently logged in user
                instance.save()  # to commit the new info
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/edit_userpage/')
            else:
                print host_form.errors
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    guide_form = HostForm()
    context = {'guide_form': guide_form}
    return render(request, 'users/host.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you do `host_form.cleaned_data.get("user")` instead of `host_form.fields['user'].instance`?

Comment: i am assuming this is to go into the views.py? if so then it starts throwing NameErrors: self is not defined and cleaned_data is not defined.

Comment: Oops, i meant host_form.cleaned_data. I fixed my comment.

Comment: it throws None and returns an integrity error.



`Django Version: 1.7.6
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: 
NOT NULL constraint failed: users_hostregistration.user_id`

Comment: i found the solution and posted my solution. thank you for your help all the same :)